# Array logic match for list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a quick links widget with different types of links/menus that the user can choose from. Only four different menu options can be shown at the same time - not more or less.

In code I first extract all the menu options which come in the form in [1,2,3...] which corresponds to the rows in a list where the menu options is stored.

The user chooses menu options is also returned in the same way with an array like [2,3,8,9] with the number corresponding which row to get from the list.

**Example:**

All menu/widgets

1. Travel
2. Hotel
3. Car
4. Buss
5. Airplane
6. Holiday

This will return an array [1,2,3,4,5,6]

And if I choose to save hotel, buss, airplane and holiday then my user settings will return [2,4,5,6].

**Problem:**
It works, until a widget is deleted from the list that the user has saved then the widget only will show three menus/links. I want the widget to always show four links, so if one is missing I need to populate the array. So if its missing, I want to show another link. It would be good, but not needed, to take a link that is set to default when its missing (always the first four in the list). I have set up a logic for that but its not working.

**Code:**

```
public async getUserWidgets(): Promise<Widget[]> {
    return new Promise<Widget[]>(async(resolve, error) => {
    let allWidgets = await this.getAllWidgets(); // Returns an array of all links [1,2,4...]

    let userRepository = new UserProfileRepository(this.absoluteWebUrl);
    let userSettings = await userRepository.getUserExtensionValues(this.context); //contains the user saved widgets ex [2,3,6,7]

    var result:Widget[] = [];
```

// if the user has no settings, or less than 4 saved links

```
    if (userSettings == null || userSettings.QuickLinksWidgets == null || userSettings.QuickLinksWidgets.length <  4) {
        result = allWidgets.filter((w) => {return w.defaultWidget;}).slice(0,4);   //default widget but not really needed.
    }
    else {
        var ids = userSettings.QuickLinksWidgets;

        for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            let id = '' + ids[i];
            let w = allWidgets.filter((e) => { return e.id == id;});

            if (w.length == 0) {
                continue;
            }

            result.push(w[0]);

        }

    };
    resolve(result);
      }); }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you described, it sounds like maybe you're not updating properly (calling `getUserWidgets` when `userSettings.QuickLinksWidgets` changes? First check to make sure it's called as you expect.

If `getUserWidgets` is being called properly, try to add defaults to their settings until you have 4 links total. Right now you are using default links if they have any less than 4 in their settings.

For example:

```js
// take up to 4 user links and make sure we don't exceed the length of the array
for (let i = 0; i < 4 && i < userSettings.QuickLinksWidgets.length - 1; i++) {
  // get the id of the widget in the user's settings
  let widgetId = userSettings.QuickLinksWidgets[i].id
  // find the widget with a matching id and add it to our results
  result.push(allWidgets.find(w => w.id === widgetId)
}

// if there's not already 4 links, add more to our list
let j = 0
while (result.length < 4) {
  // check the first 4 user links to make sure we didn't include this link already
  if (!userSettings.QuickLinksWidgets.slice(0, 4).includes(allWidgets[j].id)) {
    // add the new widget to the results
    result.push(allWidgets[j])
  }

  j++
}

resolve(result)
```